# Updating "tr" data in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

[image: Here is my code]
[image]

I'm facing difficulty in doing this task :
- I have a table that have an add delete , update buttons for every single row I've done the add and delete thing by adding data-attribute for each button according to the row's data Id. It works perfectly for deleting and inserting elements. Yet i can't find a way to update every single row so i need help !

Note: I'm updating my elements using Ajax.

Any strategy ? i can post a screenshot for my code/view cause it is a bit too long .

More explanation : when you click on the edit button $(this) and delete button hide , and check button appears . inputs are no longer hidden for this row so the user updates the data of this row then he checks it. 
The data must update inside the database . 
I'm stuck nowhere because every row has its own id and its own values and only one query must be run for every row ( which is the same query for all the rows ) . It's more likely having one form for the whole table that updates only the row that must be updated .

**After you click on edit button**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-edit-interview', function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('data-interview-id');
    var selector = ('' + '.tr' + id + '');
    var selectordelt = ('' + '.' + id + '');
    var selectorsave = ('' + '#save-'+id + '');
    $(this).hide();
    $(selectordelt).hide();
    $(selectorsave).show();
    $(selector).prop('disabled', false);
    $(selector).addClass("form-control");
    $(selector).css('border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);margin-top: 16px;');
});
```

I just need help in finding a way do make the update query for every single row .

Comment: Add the screenshot.

Comment: Ok, I don't see where the problem is ? Is it on the front end where you don't know what to do in the code when clicking the edit button, or is it in the backend ? Could you give more details and some code ?

Comment: Can i add class for every tr that takes the save id of the user , then when running ajax ('.ID-USER').serialize() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//HTML


<tr data-unique="{!! $yourVariable->id !!}">

<td><input value="{!! $yourVariable->value !!}"></td>

    <td><button data-update="{!! $yourVariable->id !!}">Update</button></td>
</tr>


//AJAX



 $('button[data-update]').click(function() {
        var itemID = $(this).attr('data-update');

       //Will contain value of input in that tr only
        var input = $('tr[data-unique="+itemID+"] input').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/update',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {item: itemID, anotherValue: input},
            success:function(data){
                   if(data['status'] == "success"){
                     alert("Updated");
                   }
            }
    });

    return false;
});



//Controller
public function update(Request $req){

   YourModel::where('id', $req->input('item'))->update(['column' => 'value']);

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
}

//Route

Route::post('/update', 'YourController@update');
```

Hope that help

Comment: how does laravel recognize the input items ? the user is updating a whole row with multiple values , please can you explain more what's happening ?

Comment: In your row, each of the columns has an input which you might probably give it a custom attribute like `data-update` with value from your controller, you can then access that in your JS and pass those values to `data` array of AJAX. Also each of the `tr` can be given a custom attribute to identify which one is being updated

Comment: Can i add class for every tr that takes the save id of the user , then when running ajax ('.ID-USER').serialize() ?

Comment: ill be working on it now and give you my updates , thank you !

Comment: Not been here. Dunno what you mean doesn't work well. Instead of picture, it's best you post your code here. That way, one can help look at what you're doing wrong